# Share DefaultHttpClient in Android

Tags: android, httpclient

I use a new httpClient with each activity like :

> DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

but I would like to share the same one with sereval activities ! Any little piece of code will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered a background service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As snowCrabs commented, you can try using a service.
Or how about using singleton? Here is a brief example so you can get an idea.

```
private static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
public DefaultHttpClient getHttpClientInstance() {
    if(httpClient==null)
        httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    return httpClient;
}
```

So you can call getHttpClientInstance from other classes.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you plan to use this from multiple threads, you might have to do a bit more and initialize the `DefaultHttpClient` with `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`.